# Dynamically added row to a table isn't visible

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to programatically add a row to my TableLayout. But it's not visible.

Here is my code:

```
// Get the TableLayout
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.table_child_data_01);

    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
    tr.setId(100);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // Create a TextView to house the name of the province
    TextView labelTV = new TextView(getActivity());
    labelTV.setId(200);
    labelTV.setText("DynamicTV");
    labelTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    labelTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tr.addView(labelTV);

    // Create a TextView to house the value of the after-tax income
    TextView valueTV = new TextView(getActivity());
    valueTV.setId(300);
    valueTV.setText("$0");
    valueTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tr.addView(valueTV);

    // Create a TextView to house the value of the after-tax income
    TextView valueTV2 = new TextView(getActivity());
    valueTV2.setId(400);
    valueTV2.setText("00");
    valueTV2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    valueTV2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tr.addView(valueTV2);

    // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    Utilities.ShowToastMsg(getActivity(), "Row added");
```

Am I missing something?

I am using `getActivity()` instead of `this` because the above code is inside Fragment and not Activity.

### Edit:

In two other threads with the same problem I found the following solutions:

Use `import TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;` instead of `import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;`

Use `TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` instead of `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` while setting layout params for TableRow tr.

But none of the above worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While setting LayoutParams. You have to keep this in mind:

-> If the view/element that you are setting LayoutParams of provides LayoutParams, use them. For example TableRow provides LayoutParams (`TableRow.LayoutParams`) so while setting LayoutParams of TableRow we need to specifically use `TableRow.LayoutParams` instead of `LayoutParams` or anything else.

-> If the view/element doesn't provide the LayoutParams itself, use the LayoutParams of the 
immediate parent that provides LayoutParams. For example in my code above the `TextView` doesn't provide the LayoutParams. So I need to see it's immediate parent i.e. TableRow (does it provide LayoutParams? yes. use that!!)

So, in the above code this:

```
tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

would become:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tr.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and

This:

```
labelTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Would become this:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams paramsTVh = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
labelTV.setLayoutParams( paramsTVh );
```

This change worked for me. Hope this will be usefull sometime for someone.